# Sqlite query returns empty cursor instead of 0

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a query which should return total `Income - total expense` for the given date

```
db.rawQuery("select (totIncome-totExpense) from  " +
   "((select coalesce(sum(amount),0) as totIncome from transaction_table where type=0 and date like '"+ ke+"'), " +
   "(select COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as totExpense from transaction_table where type=1 and date like '"+ ke+"'))",null);
```

But when there are no records for `type=0`, for a given date, the query returns an empty cursor instead of `-totExpense`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation with `sum(case...)`:

```
db.rawQuery(
  "select coalesce(sum(case type when 0 then amount else 0 end) - sum(case type when 1 then amount else 0 end), 0) as result from transaction_table where date like ?",
  new String[] {ke}
);
```

This way the sums are calculated with only one scan of the table.
The function `coalesce()` is needed only for the case that there are no rows in the table for that date.
I also took out from the query the date `ke` and passed it is a parameter, which is safer.
Maybe instead of `like` you can use `=` if `ke` is just a date and does not contain wildchars like `%` or `_`.